# Count number of likes from links collections Strapi

Tags: controller, backend, strapi

I use strapi 4 and I have 2 collections
Collection 1 : links (id, body…)
Collection 2 : likes (id, postid, userid)

I want to count all likes for on links id

I try to do this with a controller. But I have 1 error : error: allPosts.find is not a function
TypeError: allPosts.find is not a function

And I don’t know why. Can you help me ?

````js
'use strict';

/**
 *  link controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::link.link', ({ strapi }) => ({
    // Method 2: Wrapping a core action (leaves core logic in place)
  async find(ctx) {
    
    const { data, meta } = await super.find(ctx);
    const linkId = data.map((link) => link.id);
    //count all like for each post
    const allPosts = await strapi
      .db
      .query('api::like.like')
      .count({
      where: {
          postid: { $in: linkId },
        }
      });
    console.log("nombre de like dif",allPosts);

    const data2 = data.map((link) => {
      link.like = allPosts.find(
        (like) => like.attributes.postid === link.id
      );
      link = {id:link.id, ...link.attributes, like:link.like};
      return link;
    }
    );

    return { data:data2 , meta };
  },
}));```
````

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me

```js
'use strict';

/**
 *  link controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::link.link', ({ strapi }) => ({
    // Method 2: Wrapping a core action (leaves core logic in place)
  async find(ctx) {
    
    const { data, meta } = await super.find(ctx);
    const linkId = data.map((link) => link.id);

    const allPosts = await strapi.entityService.findMany('api::link.link', {
      fields: ["id"],
      filters: { id: { $in: linkId } },
      populate: {
        likes: { count: true },
      },
  });

    data.forEach(link => {
      link.likes = allPosts.find(({ id }) => id === link.id)?.likes?.count || 0;
    });


    return { data, meta };
  },
}));
```